# File fragmentation when data changes

Tags: file, io, fragmentation

If i add some letters to middle of file is that operation make file fragmentation?

I just want to store data to file and sometimes update them. So...when i made many changes is it may be bad for perfomance issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of changes size.
- If you add only few letters and after this change size of file doesn't grow above size of allocated clusters number - then it'll not affect fagmentation.
- When after adding letters system needs to allocate aditional cluster on disc - then fragmentation could increase.